# Use strings instead of PY_VAR

Tags: python, string, variables, tkinter

I don't know why but in each places where strings should be displayed I have PY_VAR# instead (# being a number).
For instance instead of displaying "This area shows messages coming from the slave" it displays PY_VAR1.
my code is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter

class Display(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.MessageString = tkinter.StringVar()
        MessageDisplay = tkinter.Label(self, text = self.MessageString, anchor = 'nw' , justify = 'left')
        MessageDisplay.grid(columnspan = 3)

        self.ClockString = tkinter.StringVar()
        ClockDisplay = tkinter.Label(self, text = self.ClockString)
        ClockDisplay.grid(row=0)

        self.Menu1Title = tkinter.StringVar()
        Menu1Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = self.Menu1Title, command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 1))
        Menu1Button.grid(column = 0, columnspan = 2)

        self.Menu2Title = tkinter.StringVar()
        Menu2Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = self.Menu2Title, command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 2))
        Menu2Button.grid(column = 0, columnspan = 2)

        self.Menu3Title = tkinter.StringVar()
        Menu3Button = tkinter.Button(self, text = self.Menu3Title, command = self.SetMenu(MenuIndex = 3))
        Menu3Button.grid(column = 0, columnspan = 2)

        self.MenuDescriptionContent = tkinter.StringVar()
        MenuDescription = tkinter.Label(self, text = self.MenuDescriptionContent, anchor = 'nw', justify = 'left')
        MenuDescription.grid(column = 2, columnspan = 2, row = 1, rowspan = 3)

        """Temporary variables"""

        self.MessageString = "This area shows messages coming from the slave"
        self.ClockString = "00:00"
        self.Menu1Title = "Menu 1"
        self.Menu2Title = "Menu 2"
        self.Menu3Title = "Menu 3"
        self.MenuDescriptionContent = "This area shows the description of the selected menu"

    def SetMenu(self, MenuIndex):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = Display(None)
app.title('Web Bell')
app.mainloop()
```

I don't have any error displayed in the console.
thank you in advance for your responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value of a StringVar you must use the `get` method:

```
MessageDisplay = tkinter.Label(..., text = self.MessageString.get(), ...)
```

The only time you don't need to do that is if you're using the StringVar as the value for a `textvariable` attribute.

You have another problem in your code. When you do `self.MessageString = "This area..."` you aren't setting the text variable, you are essentially throwing it away and changing `self.MessageString` to refer to a string.

Instead, you need to call the set method of the variable, like this:

```
self.MessageString.set("This area...")
```

Comment: while using textvariable instead of text or the get method it don't display anything.

Comment: @user2675968: your other problem is that you aren't setting them to anything. To give one of these variables a value you must use the `set` method.